# Why is "we" mentioned twice in the English translation of Ps. 20:8?

Tags: rashi, tehilim-psalms, english

In the English of Psalms 20 verse 8 "we" is translated twice both in the translation and in Rashi's notes.   I read  וַאֲנַחְנוּ  as "and we".  What am I missing?  (http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16241/jewish/Chapter-20.htm#showrashi=true)

Comment: But we,... We...Welcome to Mi Yodeya

Comment: I suspect the "wewe" in _Rashi_ there is a simple typo.

Comment: Leah welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). 

Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.

Comment: It seems the translator simply misunderstood the verse. There should only be one we.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a more colloquial translation of what they're trying to accomplish:

> Some rely on their chariots, and some on their horses, *but as for us?* We call out in the name of God!

(There is no double-we in the Hebrew, though the word *nazkir* is already conjugated as "we will call out", so the preceding word *va-anachnu*, "and we", gives it similar stress and contrast.)

Comment: +1 on this answer. I'll complement it here with the opening sentences of what I was penning as an answer but won't now post because it'd just duplicate this one: The wording in Hebrew is, more literally, "and we, in name-of God our-god, mention-[first-person-plural-imperfect/future]". The last word, the verb, is conjugated for "we" and, absent the explicit pronoun, would be translated "we will mention". *With* the explicit pronoun, the verb would normally be translated "will mention". Instead, here, Judaica Press translators (whose translation is on the Chabad site) chose to repeat the "we".

Comment: +1 this is what I want to show in my comment
Do not confuse with the french word Oui oui.

Comment: How do you it isn't a typo?

Comment: @DoubleAA they put a dash between the *we*s.

Comment: Shalom Only in one place. And that can totally be part of the typo, as it was a hyphen character not a dash character. @msh210 Did you check a different edition of the translation? (I'd rather find that it's a typo than a mistake in understanding, as there is no question in the verse.)

Comment: "gives it similar stress and contrast" What does that mean?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I don't have the Judaica Press. If I stop by a _shul_ that has it, I'll try to remember to check it. Re "a mistake in understanding, as there is no question in the verse", nor is there a question in the colloquial translation in this answer: the question mark in "as for us?" indicates not a question but just a rising tone similar to that of a question, and that rising tone indicates emphasis of the phrase and connection to what follows (perhaps better written as a dash or colon). So I don't think there's any mistake in understanding.

Comment: @msh210 Whatever it is, it's not in the verse. The verse just says "and we will call out in the name of God". What Shalom wrote is a bad translation of the Hebrew (it may be a good representation of what that translator meant to say).

Comment: @DoubleAA, according to commentaries (in _mikraos g'dolos_, but I forget which ones and don't have it before me) _vaanachnu_ is for contrast to the preceding. (This answer would do well to cite them IMO.) I didn't see any that says it's for emphasis, though.

Comment: @msh210 I suspect that translator just misread the line after the Shalshelet Gedolah as a Psik (indeed, Chabad.org for some reason includes it in their Hebrew (!)), and thought there was a pause there. (Granted Shalshelet Gedolah is technically a Mafsik, but a Mafsik is warranted when switching the verb and object at the end of verses in Tehillim (cf verses 3,4,5 in that chapter). In regular trop, that ending clause would be rendered Zakef-Gadol Merkha Tipcha Silluk.) With the parallel construction of ואנחנו with a connective Trop in the next verse, whatever doubts remain are clearly resolved.

Comment: @msh210 No one would think of translating "וְאַתָּ֣ה יְ֭הוָה לְעוֹלָ֣ם תֵּשֵׁ֑ב    וְ֝זִכְרְךָ֗ לְדֹ֣ר וָדֹֽר׃ And you God? -- You'll sit forever" even with the Mafsik on 'God'.

Comment: @DoubleAA I just checked the Judaica Press edition in print and it has "we—we" in both the verse and the _Rashi_. Fwiw.